# Arduino очистка Serial

Tags: arduino, serial

Имеется функция чтения данных с порта, записывающая массив байт

```
while (Serial.available()) {
    byte inBuf = Serial.read();     //прочитать байт по последовательному порту
    //Serial.println();
    if (i_byte < 18 && inBuf != 0x0D) {    //если байт не последний (флаг n)
      buf_command[i_byte] = inBuf;   //добавить полученный байт в массив команды
      i_byte++;

    }
```

Проблема в том, что если подать пакет не в 19, а в большее число символов, то все следующие принимаемые пакеты смещаются на это число избыточных символов (то есть избыточные байты где то в каком то буфере сохраняются) 
То есть например пакет 7E 00 0F 90 00 13 A2 00 41 54 B4 81 00 00 01 47 50 53 05 принимается хорошо, но если придет пакет 7E 00 0F 90 00 13 A2 00 41 54 B4 81 00 00 01 47 50 53 05 FF, то в первом цикле чтения запишется 19 байт, а 20-й запишется начальным в следующем цикле, можно ли как то сделать чистку буфера Serial, чтобы после приёма 19 байт, все остальные байты уничтожались, чтобы при следующем приёме пакета уже началась запись именно новых данных, а не конца старых?

Comment: Вы же вчера вопрос задавали, а от общения уклонились

Comment: Вчерашний вопрос решился традиционным переписыванием кода (всё внезапно стало читаться). Но тот рецепт тоже не спасёт от избыточности, так как там тот же счетчик

Comment: Старт-стопные признаки в пакете есть?

Comment: 7E-старт 00 0F-длина пакета, я уже подумал, делать запись массива только если байты длины соответствуют, но простота кода приоритетней сохранности пакетов, поэтому мне и проще сливать оставшиеся байты, чтобы до прихода следующего пакета (а это секунды 3 минимум) и уже принимать новый пакет на чистом Serial

Comment: Забил на это дело, сделал сброс i_byte++; при появлении 7E

Answer (score 2):

Общий принцип:

```
Завести буфер

По приходу посылки: 
     добавить её к буферу, вызвать обработку буфера

Обработка буфера: 
     найти стартовую последовательность
     если её нет:
         очистить буфер  //здесь аккуратно, если последовательность из нескольких байт
     иначе
         удалить всё до её начала
         проверить полноту пакета данных - в данном случае длину 
         (в других случаях может быть стоповая последовательность)
         если пакет валидный:
             извлечь пакет
             удалить его из буфера
             вызвать обработку пакета
```